# Differences between keyword, reserved word, and builtin?

Tags: bash

From [Make bash use external `time` command rather than shell built-in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86266/make-bash-use-external-time-command-rather-than-shell-built-in#comment128553_86269), Stéphane Chazelas wrote:

> There is no `time` bash builtin. `time` is a keyword so you can do for instance `time { foo; bar; }`

We can verify it:

```
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
```

It doesn't show that `time` can be a built-in command.

1. What is the definition of a "keyword"?
2. Is "keyword" the same concept as "reserved word" in the Bash Reference Manual?

   > reserved word
   >
   > A word that has a special meaning to the shell. Most reserved words introduce shell flow control constructs, such as `for` and
   > `while`.
3. Is a keyword necessarily not a command (or not a built-in command)?

   As a keyword, is `time` not a command (or not a built-in command)?

   Based on the definitions of keyword and of built-in, why is `time`
   not a built-in but a keyword?
4. Why "you can do for instance `time { foo; bar; }`" because "`time` is a keyword"?

Comment: In this case, "time" behave differently compared commands, so it syntax must be defined by shell. Check the point (4): "time" will measure the two commands, but this syntax is not valid for other commands.

Comment: There are three other questions that this may or may not be a duplicate of, but should definitely be linked, so here they are: [Why is echo builtin](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1355/135943), [Difference between builtin and non-builtin](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11454/135943), [Why is `[` builtin and `[[` is a keyword?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183745/135943)  (Full titles over to the right under the heading "Linked".)

Comment: Specifically this question is *mostly* answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11460/135943), but I'm not voting to close because I think it's a great question in its own right (and not *fully* answered elsewhere.)

Comment: @Wildcard: Thanks. The links are helpful. The last link doesn't answer most of my questions.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/445749/whats-the-difference-between-shell-builtin-and-shell-keyword

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keywords, reserved words, and builtins are all the "first word" of a simple command. They can be placed in two groups: Keywords and builtins. The two are mutually exclusive. A word (token) can be either a keyword or a builtin, but not both.

#### Why the "first word"

From the [POSIX definition of "simple command"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) (emphasis mine):

> A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.

> 2.- The words that are not variable assignments or redirections shall be expanded. If any fields remain following their expansion, the **first field shall be considered the command name** and remaining fields are the arguments for the command.

After that "first word" has been identified, and after is has been expanded (by an alias, for example) the final word is "the command", there could be only one command in each line. That command word could be a builtin or a keyword.

#### Keyword

Yes, a keyword is a "reserved word". Load "man bash" and search for keyword or just execute this command: `LESS=+/'keyword' man bash`.

The first hit on search says this:

> keyword Shell reserved words.

It happens in the completion section, but is quite clear.

#### Reserved words

In POSIX, there is [this definition of "reserved words"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04) and some [description of what reserved words do](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_04).

But the Bash manual has a better working definition.
Search for "RESERVED WORDS" (`LESS=+/'RESERVED WORDS' man bash`) and find this:

> RESERVED WORDS
> Reserved words are words that have a special meaning to the shell.
> The following words are recognized as reserved when unquoted and either the first word of a simple command or the third word of a case or for command:

> ```
> ! case do done elif else esac fi for function if in select then until while { } time [[ ]]
> ```

#### Builtin

It is not defined in the Bash manual, but it is quite simple:

It is a command that has been implemented inside the shell for essential needs of the shell (cd, pwd, eval), or speed in general or to avoid conflicting interpretations of external utilities in some cases.

#### Time is a keyword

> why is time not a builtin but a keyword?

To allow the existence of a command as the second word.

It is similar as how an `if ... then .... fi` allow the inclusion of commands (even compound commands) after the first keyword `if`. Or `while` or `case`, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  Why is `time` a keyword, because it is in order "To allow the existence of a command as the second word"? Can't a builtin command precede another command? If I use the external command explicitly as  `/usr/bin/time date`, it still work, so an external command can precede another command. Then why can't a builtin command precede another command?

Comment: @Tim In the `/usr/bin/time date` command line `time` is the (only) command (as the shell understand it), `date` is an argument to `time` which happens to be a command **for the user**. Not for the shell, which only see one command: `time` and one or several arguments, and `date` is one of them.

Comment: So what you meant is in `time date`, `time` is a keyword not a command, and `date` is a command and not an argument to `time`, while in `/usr/bin/time date`, `/usr/bin/time` is a command and `date` is an argument to it? Why in `time date`, is `time` not  a builtin command and `date` is an arugment to it? Can a builtin command take another command as its argument?

Comment: @Tim Because the developer of bash decided to implement it that way.

Comment: @Tim A builtin command is the command of the line, period. If the builtin decides to promote an argument to a command is the decision of the builtin (like the builtin command or eval for example).

Comment: The third word of "case" or "for" just means the word "in".

Comment: @Roland or the word "do".  `for f do` is perfectly legal and is equivalent to `for f in "$@"; do`

Answer (score 1):

#### Q1, Q2

> What's the definition of a keyword?
>
> Is "keyword" the same concept as "reserved word" in Bash Reference Manual?

Basically, special words important to the syntactic structure. In C there are `goto`, `if`, `while`, `enum` and so on; in bash you have `if`, `while` (these sound familiar..), `time`, etc.

And yes, they are the same.

I am taking some liberty in interpreting the question, since the basic syntactic elements of POSIX shell and bash are similar. So let's look at the definition in [POSIX.1:2013 Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html):

> #### [2.4](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04) Reserved Words
>
> Reserved words are words that have special meaning to the shell; see [Shell Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09). The following words shall be recognized as reserved words:
>
> ...
>
> This recognition shall only occur when none of the characters is quoted and when the word is used as:
>
> ...
>
> See the grammar in [Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10).

Let's take a look at the POSIX grammar to see how the Special Words—now syntatic tokens after lexing—in action:

```
for_clause       : For name linebreak                            do_group
                 | For name linebreak in          sequential_sep do_group
                 | For name linebreak in wordlist sequential_sep do_group
/* ... */
do_group         : Do compound_list Done           /* Apply rule 6 */
```

That looks familiar, right? Note that `For`, `Do` and `Done` are really tokens that are supposed to be mapped and recognized by the lexer:

```
%token  If    Then    Else    Elif    Fi    Do    Done
/*      'if'  'then'  'else'  'elif'  'fi'  'do'  'done'   */


%token  Case    Esac    While    Until    For
/*      'case'  'esac'  'while'  'until'  'for'   */

/* and 'In' too -- They made a mistake! */
%token  In    /*      'in'   */
```

If you have heard about [Yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) or [Bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) (or well, jison), that's how people might use the grammar. With these parsers generators, they can generate something that figures out what parts of the grammar a given flow of input 'tokens' are spoken in.

#### Q3

> Is a keyword necessarily not a command (or not a builtin command)?
>
> As a keyword, is `time` not a command (or not a builtin command)?

None of the keywords are treated like commands. But sure, you can have commands/functions with the same name, e.g.:

```
# make a command to avoid command-not-found for `FOO=BAR time cmd`
time(){ time "$@"; }
```

> Based on the definitions of keyword and of builtin, why is time not a builtin but a keyword?

Because that's how [people decided to make it](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y#n1197):

```
// Licensed under GPLv2, bash:parse.y
// Copyright (C) 1989-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
pipeline_command: pipeline
                | BANG pipeline_command
                | timespec pipeline_command
                | timespec list_terminator
                | BANG list_terminator;
pipeline        : pipeline '|' newline_list pipeline
                | pipeline BAR_AND newline_list pipeline
                | command;
timespec        : TIME | TIME TIMEOPT | TIME TIMEOPT TIMEIGN;
```

And they get extra power from this (see next question).

#### Q4

> Why "you can do for instance `time { foo; bar; }`" because "`time` is a keyword"?

As a part of the grammar, people can naturally let the parser handle everything, and make decisions like allowing `time` before compound commands. If `time` was implemented as just a command, you will get a syntax error for constructs like such (try `echo { foo; bar; }`), since it's really parsed with the 'usual' rules.

Also think about `[[`. If `[[` have not been a keyword, constructs like `[[ ($a == 2) || ($b != 3) ]]` will make the shell find stray parentheses and complain. (Replace `[[` with `[` and see).

P.S. `time` is a [utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html) instead of a keyword in POSIX, although the latter is still considered acceptable. The whole time-a-trunk-of-commands thing is a ksh and bash extension.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Not possible for the same word, but `time` means the command or function `time` when it doesn't meet the requirements of being recognized as a keyword…

Comment: Thanks. From the view of the parser or interpreter, why in `time { foo; bar; }`, must `time` be a keyword,  why can't `time be a builtin command?

Comment: @tim "Replace time with echo". It's just something that normal commands don't get interpreted as...

Comment: @Tim, the grammar doesn't allow it.  (Just like in English "I ate" is a sentence but "I kitchen" isn't, because there has to be a verb; that's just how the grammar works.)  There's two "layers" to the question you can ask: (1) What are the rules by which `echo { foo; bar;}` was disallowed in the design of shell grammar, and (2) Why were the rules designed that way.  They are really different questions; one is "how" and one is "why".