# What is the difference between `{ echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } | :` and `{ echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :` in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, command

Why can the command `{ echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } | :` print "err", but the second can not?

Some tests in container:

- [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian): 11.5 (bash/5.1.4)
- [Rocky Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_Linux): 9.0 (bash/5.1.8),
- [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS): 7.7.1908 (bash/4.2.46),
- CentOS: 8.4.2105 (bash/4.4.19).

This also happened in host CentOS 8.0.1905, Debian 11.4.

```bash
~# { echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } | :
err
~# { echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :
~#
```

And not using `:` seems right:

```bash
~# { echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | sed 's/.*/-&-/'
err
-out-
~#
```

But print in another host CentOS 7.7.1908 (bash/4.2.46):

```bash
~# { echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :
err
~#
```

Comment: I tested in a `debian:11.5` container and both commands gave output.

Comment: I had the same result on Ubuntu 18.04. Both commands had the output "err". I'm also scratching my head trying to figure out if this has any use.

Comment: FYI, `>&1` doesn't do anything. It's redirecting stdout to itself, which is a no-op.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between

```bash
{ echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } | :
```

... and

```bash
{ echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :
```

... is the order in which the two `echo` calls are made. The order matters only in terms of how *quickly* the first `echo` can execute.

The two sides of the pipeline, `{ ...; }` and `:`, are started concurrently, and `:` does not read from its standard input stream.  This means the pipe is torn down as soon as `:` terminates, which will be almost immediately.

If the pipe is torn down, there is no pipe buffer for `echo out >&1` to write to.  When `echo` tries to write to the non-existent pipe, the left-hand side of the pipeline dies from receiving a PIPE signal.

If it dies before `echo err >&2` has executed, there will be no output.

So:

- You will always get `err` as output from `{ echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } | :` since `echo err >&2` will not care about the state of the pipe.
- You will sometimes get `err` as output from `{ echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :` *depending on* whether `:` has terminated before `echo out >&1` has the chance to run.  If `:` terminates first, there will be no output due to the left-hand side getting killed prematurely.

I'm guessing that most people will not experience the non-deterministic behaviour of the second pipeline on most systems. Still, you have found combinations of operating systems and shell versions that show this.  I have also replicated the non-deterministic behaviour under `zsh` on FreeBSD, even in a single shell session (although the shell seems to tend to one behaviour rather than the other, so I needed 10+ tries to finally see the switch).

Comment: To view evidence of the SIGPIPE killing the left-hand side, you could look at `$pipestatus` in zsh or `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` in Bash. Though for whatever reason, on Bash it seems far more likely for the left-hand side to run first than on zsh. (Based on some quick testing on one system anyway.) Of course, even something like `{ sleep .01; echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :`  would tip the scales.

Comment: Interesting fact: `echo` being a builtin is crucial. Try `{ sleep 1; echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :` vs `{ sleep 1; /bin/echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :`. You may want to notice this in the answer and explain maybe (not for me particularly; I think I know why this happens).

Comment: The key here is that `echo` is builtin in most shells. If it weren't, only the child process spawned to execute `echo` would die. Here, it's the subshell process running the left hand side of the pipeline that receives a SIGPIPE when it does a `write()` to  a pipe that has no reader left.

Answer (score 2):

(firstly, if you are experimenting with things and you are not sure how they work and what they do, I highly suggest you stop doing so when logged in as `root`)

```
{ echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } | :
```

This will echo the string `err\n`, with standard output containing that string redirected to standard error (which is displayed on the terminal), followed by echoing the string `out\n` to standard output pointlessly redirected to standard output; that standard output is then piped as standard input into `:`, which outputs nothing.

Further testing:

```
$ { echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } 1> outputfile 2> errorfile
$ for file in *; do echo $file; cat $file; done
errorfile
err
outputfile
out
$ rm  errorfile outputfile
$ { echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } 1> outputfile 2> errorfile
$ for file in *; do echo $file; cat $file; done
errorfile
err
outputfile
out
```

All that said and demonstrated, I am unsure why you seem to be losing the output to standard error in some cases.  I am not able to replicate this:

```
$ { echo err >&2; echo out >&1; } | :
err
$ { echo out >&1; echo err >&2; } | :
err
```